# Login validation needs to go before actual login

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have made a special class validation to check if a user is logged in if not than it should not open the page it wants to go on. The problem is when i added the lines my program doesn't route me anymore to the component where is needs to go.

***Validation.ts***

```
export class validation {
 user = {};

  loggedinvalidation(user) {
    if (user) {
      this.user = user;
      console.log("test login");
      return true
    } else {
      this.user = {};
      console.log("test logout");
      return false
    }
  }
}
```

***app.component.ts***

```
 export class AppComponent {


...

    login(email:any, password:any) {
        this.af.auth.login({ email: email, password: password }, {
          provider: AuthProviders.Password,
          method: AuthMethods.Password
        });
        this.modal.close();
        this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
      }
    }
```

***dashboard.component.ts***

```
export class DashboardComponent {

constructor(public af: AngularFire,  public router: Router) {
    this.vali = new validation();
    this.af.auth.subscribe(user => {
      if (this.vali.loggedinvalidation(user)) {

        this.af.auth.subscribe(auth => {
...

});
      }
      else {
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
      }
    });


  }
}
```

When i run the program & start at /'' it works fine but when i try to login it gives me this in my console. The problem is its first gives me a test logout and thats why it doesn't route to the dashboard. Any idee how i can get the validation faster or afther the login actually happens?

```
test logout
test login
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolver may be help you. still you are using auth process which is logically correct but more precise solution is there for doing authentication seamlessly :)

https://www.codementor.io/max_diachenko/tutorials/angular-2-route-resolves--typescript-du1089pdm

Comment: Well i looked at the link but i still dont have any clue how i could make a resolve out of my routing